# What is the IV in this AES JavaScript function?

Tags: java, javascript, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm trying to use a JavaScript library to encrypt data and send that to a Java based server where that data can be decrypted.

The problem I'm having, is in looking at the JavaScript code, I only see evidence of a 8 byte IV, even though Java wants a 16 byte IV :-P.

Is it possible to have Java decode what is sent from the JavaScript, or modify the JavaScript so it can be? This is definitely waaaay above my crypto abilities :-P.

The script is available here:
[enter link description here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html)

My slightly modified version is below:

The current version of the Java code where I've been playing around with different things is here:

```
package com.myclass.util;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidParameterSpecException;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

   public class AES {
       private static Charset PLAIN_TEXT_ENCODING = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
       private static String CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CTR/NoPadding";
       private static String KEY_TYPE = "AES";
       private static int KEY_SIZE_BITS = 128;

       private SecretKey key;
       private Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION);
       private byte[] ivBytes = new byte[KEY_SIZE_BITS/8];

       public AES() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidParameterSpecException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException{
           KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KEY_TYPE);
           kgen.init(KEY_SIZE_BITS); 
           key = kgen.generateKey();
           cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
           ivBytes = cipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
       }

       public String getIVAsHex(){
           return byteArrayToHexString(ivBytes);
       }

       public String getKeyAsHex(){
           return byteArrayToHexString(key.getEncoded());
       }

       public void setStringToKey(String keyText) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
           setKey(getHash(keyText));
       }

       public void setHexToKey(String hexKey){
           setKey(hexStringToByteArray(hexKey));
       }

       private void setKey(byte[] bArray){
           byte[] bText = new byte[KEY_SIZE_BITS/8];
           int end = Math.min(KEY_SIZE_BITS/8, bArray.length);
           System.arraycopy(bArray, 0, bText, 0, end);
           key = new SecretKeySpec(bText, KEY_TYPE);
       }

       public void setStringToIV(String ivText){
           setIV(ivText.getBytes());
       }

       public void setHexToIV(String hexIV){
           setIV(hexStringToByteArray(hexIV));
       }

       private void setIV(byte[] bArray){
           byte[] bText = new byte[KEY_SIZE_BITS/8];
           int end = Math.min(KEY_SIZE_BITS/8, bArray.length);
           System.arraycopy(bArray, 0, bText, 0, end);
           ivBytes = bText;
       }

        public String encrypt(String message) throws InvalidKeyException,
                IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException,
                InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes(PLAIN_TEXT_ENCODING));
            String result = byteArrayToHexString(ivBytes).concat(byteArrayToHexString(encrypted).substring(2));
            return result;
        }

        public String decrypt(String hexCiphertext)
                throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException,
                InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
                UnsupportedEncodingException {
            byte[] dec = hexStringToByteArray(hexCiphertext);
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            System.arraycopy(dec, 0, iv, 0, 16);
            byte[] cText = new byte[dec.length - 16];
            System.arraycopy(dec, 16, cText, 0, cText.length);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(cText);
            return new String(decrypted, PLAIN_TEXT_ENCODING);
        }

        private static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] raw) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2 + raw.length * 2);
            sb.append("0x");
            for (int i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
                sb.append(String.format("%02X", Integer.valueOf(raw[i] & 0xFF)));
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

       private static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String hex) {
            Pattern replace = Pattern.compile("^0x");
            String s = replace.matcher(hex).replaceAll("");

            byte[] b = new byte[s.length() / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
              int index = i * 2;
              int v = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(index, index + 2), 16);
              b[i] = (byte)v;
            }
            return b;
       }
       private byte[] getHash(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
           MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
           digest.reset();
           return digest.digest(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        }

       public String getHashasHex(String password) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException{
           return byteArrayToHexString(getHash(password));
       }

   }


/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */
/*  AES implementation in JavaScript (c) Chris Veness 2005-2011                                   */
/*   - see http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/PubsFIPS.html#197                                    */
/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */

var Aes = {};  // Aes namespace

/**
 * AES Cipher function: encrypt 'input' state with Rijndael algorithm
 *   applies Nr rounds (10/12/14) using key schedule w for 'add round key' stage
 *
 * @param {Number[]} input 16-byte (128-bit) input state array
 * @param {Number[][]} w   Key schedule as 2D byte-array (Nr+1 x Nb bytes)
 * @returns {Number[]}     Encrypted output state array
 */
Aes.cipher = function(input, w) {    // main Cipher function [§5.1]
  var Nb = 4;               // block size (in words): no of columns in state (fixed at 4 for AES)
  var Nr = w.length/Nb - 1; // no of rounds: 10/12/14 for 128/192/256-bit keys

  var state = [[],[],[],[]];  // initialise 4xNb byte-array 'state' with input [§3.4]
  for (var i=0; i<4*Nb; i++) state[i%4][Math.floor(i/4)] = input[i];

  state = Aes.addRoundKey(state, w, 0, Nb);

  for (var round=1; round<Nr; round++) {
    state = Aes.subBytes(state, Nb);
    state = Aes.shiftRows(state, Nb);
    state = Aes.mixColumns(state, Nb);
    state = Aes.addRoundKey(state, w, round, Nb);
  }

  state = Aes.subBytes(state, Nb);
  state = Aes.shiftRows(state, Nb);
  state = Aes.addRoundKey(state, w, Nr, Nb);

  var output = new Array(4*Nb);  // convert state to 1-d array before returning [§3.4]
  for (var i=0; i<4*Nb; i++) output[i] = state[i%4][Math.floor(i/4)];
  return output;
}

/**
 * Perform Key Expansion to generate a Key Schedule
 *
 * @param {Number[]} key Key as 16/24/32-byte array
 * @returns {Number[][]} Expanded key schedule as 2D byte-array (Nr+1 x Nb bytes)
 */
Aes.keyExpansion = function(key) {  // generate Key Schedule (byte-array Nr+1 x Nb) from Key [§5.2]
  var Nb = 4;            // block size (in words): no of columns in state (fixed at 4 for AES)
  var Nk = key.length/4  // key length (in words): 4/6/8 for 128/192/256-bit keys
  var Nr = Nk + 6;       // no of rounds: 10/12/14 for 128/192/256-bit keys

  var w = new Array(Nb*(Nr+1));
  var temp = new Array(4);

  for (var i=0; i<Nk; i++) {
    var r = [key[4*i], key[4*i+1], key[4*i+2], key[4*i+3]];
    w[i] = r;
  }

  for (var i=Nk; i<(Nb*(Nr+1)); i++) {
    w[i] = new Array(4);
    for (var t=0; t<4; t++) temp[t] = w[i-1][t];
    if (i % Nk == 0) {
      temp = Aes.subWord(Aes.rotWord(temp));
      for (var t=0; t<4; t++) temp[t] ^= Aes.rCon[i/Nk][t];
    } else if (Nk > 6 && i%Nk == 4) {
      temp = Aes.subWord(temp);
    }
    for (var t=0; t<4; t++) w[i][t] = w[i-Nk][t] ^ temp[t];
  }

  return w;
}

/*
 * ---- remaining routines are private, not called externally ----
 */

Aes.subBytes = function(s, Nb) {    // apply SBox to state S [§5.1.1]
  for (var r=0; r<4; r++) {
    for (var c=0; c<Nb; c++) s[r][c] = Aes.sBox[s[r][c]];
  }
  return s;
}

Aes.shiftRows = function(s, Nb) {    // shift row r of state S left by r bytes [§5.1.2]
  var t = new Array(4);
  for (var r=1; r<4; r++) {
    for (var c=0; c<4; c++) t[c] = s[r][(c+r)%Nb];  // shift into temp copy
    for (var c=0; c<4; c++) s[r][c] = t[c];         // and copy back
  }          // note that this will work for Nb=4,5,6, but not 7,8 (always 4 for AES):
  return s;  // see asmaes.sourceforge.net/rijndael/rijndaelImplementation.pdf
}

Aes.mixColumns = function(s, Nb) {   // combine bytes of each col of state S [§5.1.3]
  for (var c=0; c<4; c++) {
    var a = new Array(4);  // 'a' is a copy of the current column from 's'
    var b = new Array(4);  // 'b' is a•{02} in GF(2^8)
    for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
      a[i] = s[i][c];
      b[i] = s[i][c]&0x80 ? s[i][c]<<1 ^ 0x011b : s[i][c]<<1;

    }
    // a[n] ^ b[n] is a•{03} in GF(2^8)
    s[0][c] = b[0] ^ a[1] ^ b[1] ^ a[2] ^ a[3]; // 2*a0 + 3*a1 + a2 + a3
    s[1][c] = a[0] ^ b[1] ^ a[2] ^ b[2] ^ a[3]; // a0 * 2*a1 + 3*a2 + a3
    s[2][c] = a[0] ^ a[1] ^ b[2] ^ a[3] ^ b[3]; // a0 + a1 + 2*a2 + 3*a3
    s[3][c] = a[0] ^ b[0] ^ a[1] ^ a[2] ^ b[3]; // 3*a0 + a1 + a2 + 2*a3
  }
  return s;
}

Aes.addRoundKey = function(state, w, rnd, Nb) {  // xor Round Key into state S [§5.1.4]
  for (var r=0; r<4; r++) {
    for (var c=0; c<Nb; c++) state[r][c] ^= w[rnd*4+c][r];
  }
  return state;
}

Aes.subWord = function(w) {    // apply SBox to 4-byte word w
  for (var i=0; i<4; i++) w[i] = Aes.sBox[w[i]];
  return w;
}

Aes.rotWord = function(w) {    // rotate 4-byte word w left by one byte
  var tmp = w[0];
  for (var i=0; i<3; i++) w[i] = w[i+1];
  w[3] = tmp;
  return w;
}

// sBox is pre-computed multiplicative inverse in GF(2^8) used in subBytes and keyExpansion [§5.1.1]
Aes.sBox =  [0x63,0x7c,0x77,0x7b,0xf2,0x6b,0x6f,0xc5,0x30,0x01,0x67,0x2b,0xfe,0xd7,0xab,0x76,
             0xca,0x82,0xc9,0x7d,0xfa,0x59,0x47,0xf0,0xad,0xd4,0xa2,0xaf,0x9c,0xa4,0x72,0xc0,
             0xb7,0xfd,0x93,0x26,0x36,0x3f,0xf7,0xcc,0x34,0xa5,0xe5,0xf1,0x71,0xd8,0x31,0x15,
             0x04,0xc7,0x23,0xc3,0x18,0x96,0x05,0x9a,0x07,0x12,0x80,0xe2,0xeb,0x27,0xb2,0x75,
             0x09,0x83,0x2c,0x1a,0x1b,0x6e,0x5a,0xa0,0x52,0x3b,0xd6,0xb3,0x29,0xe3,0x2f,0x84,
             0x53,0xd1,0x00,0xed,0x20,0xfc,0xb1,0x5b,0x6a,0xcb,0xbe,0x39,0x4a,0x4c,0x58,0xcf,
             0xd0,0xef,0xaa,0xfb,0x43,0x4d,0x33,0x85,0x45,0xf9,0x02,0x7f,0x50,0x3c,0x9f,0xa8,
             0x51,0xa3,0x40,0x8f,0x92,0x9d,0x38,0xf5,0xbc,0xb6,0xda,0x21,0x10,0xff,0xf3,0xd2,
             0xcd,0x0c,0x13,0xec,0x5f,0x97,0x44,0x17,0xc4,0xa7,0x7e,0x3d,0x64,0x5d,0x19,0x73,
             0x60,0x81,0x4f,0xdc,0x22,0x2a,0x90,0x88,0x46,0xee,0xb8,0x14,0xde,0x5e,0x0b,0xdb,
             0xe0,0x32,0x3a,0x0a,0x49,0x06,0x24,0x5c,0xc2,0xd3,0xac,0x62,0x91,0x95,0xe4,0x79,
             0xe7,0xc8,0x37,0x6d,0x8d,0xd5,0x4e,0xa9,0x6c,0x56,0xf4,0xea,0x65,0x7a,0xae,0x08,
             0xba,0x78,0x25,0x2e,0x1c,0xa6,0xb4,0xc6,0xe8,0xdd,0x74,0x1f,0x4b,0xbd,0x8b,0x8a,
             0x70,0x3e,0xb5,0x66,0x48,0x03,0xf6,0x0e,0x61,0x35,0x57,0xb9,0x86,0xc1,0x1d,0x9e,
             0xe1,0xf8,0x98,0x11,0x69,0xd9,0x8e,0x94,0x9b,0x1e,0x87,0xe9,0xce,0x55,0x28,0xdf,
             0x8c,0xa1,0x89,0x0d,0xbf,0xe6,0x42,0x68,0x41,0x99,0x2d,0x0f,0xb0,0x54,0xbb,0x16];

// rCon is Round Constant used for the Key Expansion [1st col is 2^(r-1) in GF(2^8)] [§5.2]
Aes.rCon = [ [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00],
             [0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00],
             [0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00],
             [0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00],
             [0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00],
             [0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00],
             [0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00],
             [0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00],
             [0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00],
             [0x1b, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00],
             [0x36, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00] ]; 


/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */
/*  AES Counter-mode implementation in JavaScript (c) Chris Veness 2005-2011                      */
/*   - see http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38a/sp800-38a.pdf                       */
/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */

Aes.Ctr = {};  // Aes.Ctr namespace: a subclass or extension of Aes

/** 
 * Encrypt a text using AES encryption in Counter mode of operation
 *
 * Unicode multi-byte character safe
 *
 * @param {String} plaintext Source text to be encrypted
 * @param {String} password  The password to use to generate a key
 * @param {Number} nBits     Number of bits to be used in the key (128, 192, or 256)
 * @returns {string}         Encrypted text
 */
Aes.Ctr.encrypt = function(plaintext, password, nBits) {
  var blockSize = 16;  // block size fixed at 16 bytes / 128 bits (Nb=4) for AES
  if (!(nBits==128 || nBits==192 || nBits==256)) return '';  // standard allows 128/192/256 bit keys
  plaintext = Utf8.encode(plaintext);
  password = Utf8.encode(password);
  //var t = new Date();  // timer

  var nBytes = nBits/8;  // no bytes in key (16/24/32)
  var hash = Sha256.hash(password);

  for (var i=0; i<nBytes; i++) {  // use 1st 16/24/32 chars of hash for key
    key[i] = isNaN(password.charCodeAt(i)) ? 0 : hash.charCodeAt(i);
  }

  // initialise 1st 8 bytes of counter block with nonce (NIST SP800-38A §B.2): [0-1] = millisec, 
  // [2-3] = random, [4-7] = seconds, together giving full sub-millisec uniqueness up to Feb 2106
  var counterBlock = new Array(blockSize);

  var nonce = (new Date()).getTime();  // timestamp: milliseconds since 1-Jan-1970
  var nonceMs = nonce%1000;
  var nonceSec = Math.floor(nonce/1000);
  var nonceRnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*0xffff);

  for (var i=0; i<2; i++) counterBlock[i]   = (nonceMs  >>> i*8) & 0xff;
  for (var i=0; i<2; i++) counterBlock[i+2] = (nonceRnd >>> i*8) & 0xff;
  for (var i=0; i<4; i++) counterBlock[i+4] = (nonceSec >>> i*8) & 0xff;

  // and convert it to a string to go on the front of the ciphertext
  var ctrTxt = '';
  for (var i=0; i<8; i++) ctrTxt += String.fromCharCode(counterBlock[i]);

  // generate key schedule - an expansion of the key into distinct Key Rounds for each round
  var keySchedule = Aes.keyExpansion(key);

  var blockCount = Math.ceil(plaintext.length/blockSize);
  var ciphertxt = new Array(blockCount);  // ciphertext as array of strings

  for (var b=0; b<blockCount; b++) {
    // set counter (block #) in last 8 bytes of counter block (leaving nonce in 1st 8 bytes)
    // done in two stages for 32-bit ops: using two words allows us to go past 2^32 blocks (68GB)
    for (var c=0; c<4; c++) counterBlock[15-c] = (b >>> c*8) & 0xff;
    for (var c=0; c<4; c++) counterBlock[15-c-4] = (b/0x100000000 >>> c*8)

    var cipherCntr = Aes.cipher(counterBlock, keySchedule);  // -- encrypt counter block --

    // block size is reduced on final block
    var blockLength = b<blockCount-1 ? blockSize : (plaintext.length-1)%blockSize+1;
    var cipherChar = new Array(blockLength);

    for (var i=0; i<blockLength; i++) {  // -- xor plaintext with ciphered counter char-by-char --
      cipherChar[i] = cipherCntr[i] ^ plaintext.charCodeAt(b*blockSize+i);
      cipherChar[i] = String.fromCharCode(cipherChar[i]);
    }
    ciphertxt[b] = cipherChar.join(''); 
  }

  // Array.join is more efficient than repeated string concatenation in IE
  var ciphertext = ctrTxt + ciphertxt.join('');
  ciphertext = stringToHex(ciphertext);  // encode in base64

  //alert((new Date()) - t);
  return ciphertext;
}

/** 
 * Decrypt a text encrypted by AES in counter mode of operation
 *
 * @param {String} ciphertext Source text to be encrypted
 * @param {String} password   The password to use to generate a key
 * @param {Number} nBits      Number of bits to be used in the key (128, 192, or 256)
 * @returns {String}          Decrypted text
 */
Aes.Ctr.decrypt = function(ciphertext, password, nBits) {
  var blockSize = 16;  // block size fixed at 16 bytes / 128 bits (Nb=4) for AES
  if (!(nBits==128 || nBits==192 || nBits==256)) return '';  // standard allows 128/192/256 bit keys
  ciphertext = hexToString(ciphertext);
  password = Utf8.encode(password);
  //var t = new Date();  // timer

  // use SHA256 to hash password (mirroring encrypt routine)
  var nBytes = nBits/8;  // no bytes in key
  var hash = Sha256.hash(password);

  for (var i=0; i<nBytes; i++) {  // use 1st 16/24/32 chars of hash for key
    key[i] = isNaN(password.charCodeAt(i)) ? 0 : hash.charCodeAt(i);
  }

  // recover nonce from 1st 8 bytes of ciphertext
  var counterBlock = new Array(8);
  ctrTxt = ciphertext.slice(0, 8);
  for (var i=0; i<8; i++) counterBlock[i] = ctrTxt.charCodeAt(i);

  // generate key schedule
  var keySchedule = Aes.keyExpansion(key);

  // separate ciphertext into blocks (skipping past initial 8 bytes)
  var nBlocks = Math.ceil((ciphertext.length-8) / blockSize);
  var ct = new Array(nBlocks);
  for (var b=0; b<nBlocks; b++) ct[b] = ciphertext.slice(8+b*blockSize, 8+b*blockSize+blockSize);
  ciphertext = ct;  // ciphertext is now array of block-length strings

  // plaintext will get generated block-by-block into array of block-length strings
  var plaintxt = new Array(ciphertext.length);

  for (var b=0; b<nBlocks; b++) {
    // set counter (block #) in last 8 bytes of counter block (leaving nonce in 1st 8 bytes)
    for (var c=0; c<4; c++) counterBlock[15-c] = ((b) >>> c*8) & 0xff;
    for (var c=0; c<4; c++) counterBlock[15-c-4] = (((b+1)/0x100000000-1) >>> c*8) & 0xff;

    var cipherCntr = Aes.cipher(counterBlock, keySchedule);  // encrypt counter block

    var plaintxtByte = new Array(ciphertext[b].length);
    for (var i=0; i<ciphertext[b].length; i++) {
      // -- xor plaintxt with ciphered counter byte-by-byte --
      plaintxtByte[i] = cipherCntr[i] ^ ciphertext[b].charCodeAt(i);
      plaintxtByte[i] = String.fromCharCode(plaintxtByte[i]);
    }
    plaintxt[b] = plaintxtByte.join('');
  }

  // join array of blocks into single plaintext string
  var plaintext = plaintxt.join('');
  plaintext = Utf8.decode(plaintext);  // decode from UTF8 back to Unicode multi-byte chars

  //alert((new Date()) - t);
  return plaintext;
}

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */
/*  Utf8 class: encode / decode between multi-byte Unicode characters and UTF-8 multiple          */
/*              single-byte character encoding (c) Chris Veness 2002-2011                         */
/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */

var Utf8 = {};  // Utf8 namespace

/**
 * Encode multi-byte Unicode string into utf-8 multiple single-byte characters 
 * (BMP / basic multilingual plane only)
 *
 * Chars in range U+0080 - U+07FF are encoded in 2 chars, U+0800 - U+FFFF in 3 chars
 *
 * @param {String} strUni Unicode string to be encoded as UTF-8
 * @returns {String} encoded string
 */
Utf8.encode = function(strUni) {
  // use regular expressions & String.replace callback function for better efficiency 
  // than procedural approaches
  var strUtf = strUni.replace(
      /[\u0080-\u07ff]/g,  // U+0080 - U+07FF => 2 bytes 110yyyyy, 10zzzzzz
      function(c) { 
        var cc = c.charCodeAt(0);
        return String.fromCharCode(0xc0 | cc>>6, 0x80 | cc&0x3f); }
    );
  strUtf = strUtf.replace(
      /[\u0800-\uffff]/g,  // U+0800 - U+FFFF => 3 bytes 1110xxxx, 10yyyyyy, 10zzzzzz
      function(c) { 
        var cc = c.charCodeAt(0); 
        return String.fromCharCode(0xe0 | cc>>12, 0x80 | cc>>6&0x3F, 0x80 | cc&0x3f); }
    );
  return strUtf;
}

/**
 * Decode utf-8 encoded string back into multi-byte Unicode characters
 *
 * @param {String} strUtf UTF-8 string to be decoded back to Unicode
 * @returns {String} decoded string
 */
Utf8.decode = function(strUtf) {
  // note: decode 3-byte chars first as decoded 2-byte strings could appear to be 3-byte char!
  var strUni = strUtf.replace(
      /[\u00e0-\u00ef][\u0080-\u00bf][\u0080-\u00bf]/g,  // 3-byte chars
      function(c) {  // (note parentheses for precence)
        var cc = ((c.charCodeAt(0)&0x0f)<<12) | ((c.charCodeAt(1)&0x3f)<<6) | ( c.charCodeAt(2)&0x3f); 
        return String.fromCharCode(cc); }
    );
  strUni = strUni.replace(
      /[\u00c0-\u00df][\u0080-\u00bf]/g,                 // 2-byte chars
      function(c) {  // (note parentheses for precence)
        var cc = (c.charCodeAt(0)&0x1f)<<6 | c.charCodeAt(1)&0x3f;
        return String.fromCharCode(cc); }
    );
  return strUni;
}

function stringToHex (s) {
  var r = "0x";
  var hexes = new Array ("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f");
  for (var i=0; i<s.length; i++) {r += hexes [s.charCodeAt(i) >> 4] + hexes [s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xf];}
  return r;
}

function hexToString (h) {
  var r = "";
  for (var i= (h.substr(0, 2)=="0x")?2:0; i<h.length; i+=2) {r += String.fromCharCode (parseInt (h.substr (i, 2), 16));}
  return r;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried out printing intermediate values (in hex?). You may also want to try the NIST test vectors for both implementations, they can be found [here](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38a/sp800-38a.pdf). I havent got a good JavaScript environment here, so debugging that is a bit tricky.

Comment: Those test vectors are not UTF-8 of course, forget I suggested that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IV was actually only 8, not 16.

I found the following discussion eventually:
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1525978&start=15&tstart=0

Based on that I updated my code to the following:

```
package com.myclass.util;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidParameterSpecException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

   public class AES {
       private static Charset PLAIN_TEXT_ENCODING = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
       private static String CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CTR/NoPadding";
       private static String KEY_TYPE = "AES";
       private static int KEY_SIZE_BITS = 128;

       private SecretKey key;
       private Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION);
       private byte[] ivBytes = new byte[KEY_SIZE_BITS/8];

       public AES() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidParameterSpecException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException{
           KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KEY_TYPE);
           kgen.init(KEY_SIZE_BITS); 
           key = kgen.generateKey();
           cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
           ivBytes = cipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
       }

       public String getIVAsHex(){
           return byteArrayToHexString(ivBytes);
       }

       public String getKeyAsHex(){
           return byteArrayToHexString(key.getEncoded());
       }

       public void setCrtKey(String keyText) throws InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException{
           byte[] bText = keyText.getBytes();
           SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(bText, "AES");
           Cipher c2 = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
           c2.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
           bText = c2.doFinal(bText);
           key = new SecretKeySpec(bText, "AES");
       }

       public void setStringToKey(String keyText) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
           setKey(keyText.getBytes());
       }

       public void setHexToKey(String hexKey){
           setKey(hexStringToByteArray(hexKey));
       }

       private void setKey(byte[] bArray){
           byte[] bText = new byte[KEY_SIZE_BITS/8];
           int end = Math.min(KEY_SIZE_BITS/8, bArray.length);
           System.arraycopy(bArray, 0, bText, 0, end);
           key = new SecretKeySpec(bText, KEY_TYPE);
       }

       public void setStringToIV(String ivText){
           setIV(ivText.getBytes());
       }

       public void setHexToIV(String hexIV){
           setIV(hexStringToByteArray(hexIV));
       }

       private void setIV(byte[] bArray){
           byte[] bText = new byte[KEY_SIZE_BITS/8];
           int end = Math.min(KEY_SIZE_BITS/8, bArray.length);
           System.arraycopy(bArray, 0, bText, 0, end);
           ivBytes = bText;
       }

        public String encryptCRT(String message) throws InvalidKeyException,
                IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException,
                InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
            String hexMessage = encrypt(message);
            return byteArrayToHexString(ivBytes).concat(hexMessage.substring(2));
        }

        public String encrypt(String message) throws InvalidKeyException,
                IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException,
                InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes(PLAIN_TEXT_ENCODING));
            String result = byteArrayToHexString(encrypted);
            return result;
        }

        public String decryptCrt(String hexCipherText) throws InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException{
            byte[] ciphertextBytes = hexStringToByteArray(hexCipherText);
            ivBytes = Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.copyOf(ciphertextBytes, 8), 16);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));
            byte[] recoveredCleartext = cipher.doFinal(ciphertextBytes, 8, ciphertextBytes.length - 8);
            return new String(recoveredCleartext);
        }


        public String decrypt(String hexCiphertext)
                throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException,
                InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
                UnsupportedEncodingException {
            byte[] dec = hexStringToByteArray(hexCiphertext);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(dec);
            return new String(decrypted, PLAIN_TEXT_ENCODING);
        }

        private static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] raw) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2 + raw.length * 2);
            sb.append("0x");
            for (int i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
                sb.append(String.format("%02X", Integer.valueOf(raw[i] & 0xFF)));
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

       private static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String hex) {
            Pattern replace = Pattern.compile("^0x");
            String s = replace.matcher(hex).replaceAll("");

            byte[] b = new byte[s.length() / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
              int index = i * 2;
              int v = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(index, index + 2), 16);
              b[i] = (byte)v;
            }
            return b;
       }
   }
```

Which is called like the following:

```
String keyString = "0123456789ABCDEF";
String hexCipherText = "0xe001ea0658fc084fe1f80204f8659484025cdcfb461f2a2e1e4090581a188870bc331b0328a7c94c030bddabf2a1";
AES e = new AES();

e.setCrtKey(keyString);
out.println(e.decryptCrt(hexCipherText));
```

And it works beautifully ;-).

Comment: Well done Doug, I posted same answer, but you were quicker :)

Comment: Now to point out a few mistakes: the full IV is the block size, not the key size. I would create a `setMessageNonce()` () that auto sets the other 8 IV bytes to 00h, and keep the `IvParameterSpec` as field. Furthermore, in Java, you cannot confuse characters for bytes (JavaScript happily does this). `setStringToIV()` may happily fail you without warning, which is why I reverted to hex in the code I gave you. Oh, and it's CTR, not CRT (which means Chinese Remainder Theorem for us crypto buffs, which is something else entirely).

Answer (score 2):

Technically yes they can read what the other is writing.  However, the Javascript code says the InputVector (IV) is 16 bytes:

```
* @param {Number[]} input 16-byte (128-bit) input state array
```

And, Java has 128/8 = 16 IV byte array in it.  So your original question seems like isn't an issue since both use 16 byte IVs.

Now for all of the issues I see with what you're doing.  Encrypting on the client (web browser) is NOT secure.  You can't make it secure.  AES is a symmetric encryption algorithm and requires the same secret key at both ends.  Which means you have to share that secret between the client and server.  That basically means that secret key has to be visible so the Javascript code can get a key that's agreeable with the server.  You can even transfer it over SSL or whatever, but no matter what anyone with a browser can grab that secret key.  And not to mention its tremendously easy to fire up firebug and grab whatever I want out of your Javascript program.  Bottom line is encrypting the data using Javascript is a pointless exercise.  If you really need to transfer secrets on the client to the server use SSL.  It's designed to be secure, it's battle tested, there are and have been issues with it.  However, they have and will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I had been misreading some of the JavaScript before. That looks like what I needed, I'm going to test it and come back.

I'm not concerned about the security aspects. The goal is actually to be insecure with something that looks secure ;-). I'm using this for a lab to teach Firebug and other tools used for web application assessments. It mimics something I've seen someone actually doing in the field.

(What has been amazing me is how much effort they must have spent to put an ineffective security measure in place. )

Comment: Haha well good.  Sounds like an interesting class.  Wish I could listen to it. :-)

Comment: Okay, I'm either not doing something right, or that code does something a little different than what the comment seems to suggest.

The actual encrypt routine is:
Aes.Ctr.encrypt

The value of counterBlock appears to be what is passed to aes.cipher the first time, and therefore I would think would be the IV.

As a result I commented all the lines setting in random values there, and changed it to be 16 bytes of null for the IV:
for(var i=0; i<16; i++)
      counterBlock[i] = 0;

This should give me an IV of 16 nulls, which for AES 128 should work, but the Java doesn't decrypt it.

Comment: +1 on using SSL and not trying to roll your own encryption in the browser.

Comment: wrschneider99 - I agree +12 for SSL, LOL. However, being that I'm trying to do things the "wrong way" on purpose for a lab... the best practice doesn't exactly work here.